# Web Login Authentication with Python, Requests, Session

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am attempting to do session login that requires csrf token.

```
import requests
from requests import Session
login = ''
profile = ''

r = requests.get(login)
payload = {
    'login': '',
    'pass': '',
    'logclick': '',
    'uber_csrf_key': '',
    'uber_csrf_token': '',
    }

Session.post(url = login, cookies = r.cookies, data = payload)
test = Session.get(profile)
print(test)
```

This returns this error message:

> TypeError: Session.post() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'self'

and I am having a difficult time finding manual for this library. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have imported `Session`, but missed to instantiate it.

This should work:

```
import requests
from requests import Session
login = ''
profile = ''

sess = Session()
r = requests.get(login)
payload = {
    'login': '',
    'pass': '',
    'logclick': '',
    'uber_csrf_key': '',
    'uber_csrf_token': '',
    }

sess.post(url = login, cookies = r.cookies, data = payload)
test = sess.get(profile)
print(test)
sess.close()
```

You may put even the get request into the session, it would help to keep everything in one session.

You may official documentation here: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: This seems to have solved the issue. Thank you very much.